# Many keys corresponds to many values data structure. Is there anything like this exist?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, computer-science

I have a set of events - let's say `[event1, event2, .., eventN]` and set of event handlers `[handler1, handler2, .., handlerK]` and each handler could be assigned to several events. For example - `Handler6` assigned to `Event1, Event2, Event5`

But my tipycal request is opposite - I need all handlers for selected event.

Is there any kind of data structure which could store this data correspondence in memory and retrieve data effectively (not worse than `O(log(n))`)

Comment: You might reduce the original mapping to a Stream of tuples, and then recollect them to create the inverted map, using the technique described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086686/java-8-stream-collect-and-group-by-objects-that-map-to-multiple-keys

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do is something like a many to many relationship.
Each event will have a list of handlers and for each handlers a list of events.

You can also try to use [Do we have a MultiBiMap ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390923/do-we-have-a-multibimap) or MultiKeyMap from Apache Guava https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html